# Download Videos from Youtube with Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, youtube

I am hoping to write a script that will allow for the detection of video on a url and provide a download link to a *flv for google chrome.

Anyone have any suggestions were to start and get a footing?

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want to reinvent the wheel: http://bitbucket.org/rg3/youtube-dl